# Return contents of the first item at index

Tags: javascript, zapier

I'm building a custom integration in Zapier, and have run into an issue where the API call I'm making (to Mavenlink) is returning an object with an arbitrary key (235896815 in the example below). However, Zapier can only use arrays (not objects) when returning results. I need a way to get the array within the returned object without knowing what the key is. One potential idea I had would be to always return the results of the first object at index. Would that be the best way to solve this? If so, how would I go about doing so? Open to other ideas as well.

Example output:

```
{
  "235896915": {
    "can_edit": true,
    "subject_type": "story",
    "account_id": 4150797,
    "subject_id": 390078195,
    "updated_at": "2019-03-21T14:26:16-07:00",
    "value": [
      1406325
    ],
    "display_value": "Nicole Patel",
    "setter_id": "10149395",
    "custom_field_id": "181017",
    "created_at": "2019-03-21T14:26:16-07:00",
    "custom_field_name": "Active Assignee",
    "type": "single",
    "id": "235896915"
  }
}
```

and here's the call I'm making:

````
const options = {
  url: `https://api.mavenlink.com/api/v1/custom_field_values.json?subject_type=story&with_subject_id=${bundle.inputData.subject_id}`,
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${bundle.authData.access_token}`,
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  },
  params: {
    'subject_id': bundle.inputData.with_subject_id,
    'id': bundle.inputData.id,
    'display_value': 'Active Assignee'
  }
}

return z.request(options)
  .then((response) => {
    response.throwForStatus();
    const results = z.JSON.parse(response.content);

    // You can do any parsing you need for results here before returning them

    return results.custom_field_values; //return object in an array
  });
```
````

Comment: is there only ever on key? In this case, `235896915`. If there's more than one, do you want to return them all?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your object into an array with Object.values.

```
var arr = Object.values(results);
```